# How to prevent 'enter' key from pressing a button with a form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form, which has a button within it that runs a JS function when pressed. When filling out the form, if I press 'enter' it runs that function, instead of submitting the form.  How can I prevent this?

e.g.

```html
<form>
     <input name="input1">
        <section>
            <input name="input2">
            <button onclick="return deleteThisSection()">Delete</button>
        </section>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

So in the above example, if the cursor is in the "input1" or "input2" box, and I press enter, the "deleteThisSection" function is run, instead of the form being submitted.

Comment: So you want the form to submit?

Comment: That's interesting browser behavior: Pressing enter both triggers the onclick of the Delete button, as well as submitting the form.

Comment: Because a button by default is `type="submit"`

Comment: @amphetamachine, no it does not submit the form, only triggers the onclick of the button

Answer (score 2):

Declare this button as a type of button. By default a button in a from is declared as 
`type="submit"`

.

```
        <button type="button" onclick="return deleteThisSection()">Delete</button>
```

Comment: @amphetamachine ty

Answer (score 1):

You can add your function to submit form event: 
`$('form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        deleteThisSection(); //Add your code or call function here
        return false;
    });`